# Flutter Algolia search multiple indices

Tags: flutter, dart, algolia

Inside my Algolia application I have to indices which both contain *users*. Both of them must have a `uid` and a `username` (along other fields). I managed to implement the search for on of the indices. But how can I search in both indices?

I followed [this](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/getting-started/flutter/) tutorial but it does not say anything about searching multiple indices.

I found [this](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/multiple-queries/) about searching multiple indices but how can I do that in Flutter in combination with `[Hits Searcher](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/instantsearch/flutter/) and [infinite_scrolling_pagination](https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll_pagination).

This is my setup:

```
 Stream<SearchMetadata> get _searchUsersMetadata =>
      _userSearcher.responses.map(
        SearchMetadata.fromResponse,
      );

  final PagingController<int, AlgoliaUser> _pagingController =
      PagingController(firstPageKey: 0);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _searchPage.listen((page) {
      if (page.pageKey == 0) {
        _pagingController.refresh();
      }
      _pagingController.appendPage(page.items, page.nextPageKey);
    }).onError((error) => _pagingController.error = error);

    _pagingController.addPageRequestListener(
      (pageKey) => _userSearcher.applyState(
        (state) => state.copyWith(page: pageKey),
      ),
    );
  }

  final _userSearcher = HitsSearcher(
    applicationID: 'myAppID',
    apiKey: 'myApiKey',
    indexName: 'users',
  );

  Stream<HitsPage> get _searchPage => _userSearcher.responses.map(
        HitsPage.fromResponse,
      );

  _onSearchChanged(String query) {
    if (_debounce?.isActive ?? false) {
      _debounce?.cancel();
    }

    _debounce = Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
      _userSearcher.applyState(
        (state) => state.copyWith(
          query: _searchTextEditingController.text,
          page: 0,
        ),
      );
    });
  }
```

Comment: nope... unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

Check package algolia_lite on pub.dev

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).